# Sending file to ftp server?

Tags: android, ftp, apache-commons

I am coding to send a file on ftp server, but it is giving an error.

```
private void connectToFTPAddress() {
       pd = ProgressDialog.show(upload_download.this, "", "Connecting...",
                true, false);


       new Thread(new Runnable() {
           public void run() {
                boolean status = false;
                status = ftpclient.ftpConnect("xxx.xxx.xxx.x","xxxxxx","xxxxxx", xx);

                if (status == true) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection Success");
                      f1.wait_wind("Connection Success", getApplicationContext());
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(0);

                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Connection failed");
                    handler.sendEmptyMessage(-1);

                }
            }

        }).start();

   }
```

Comment: What error are you getting

Comment: Attempted to unregister already unregistered input channel '5387d6ac

Comment: i have used commons-net.jar library